# Notation for all possible permutations describing the multiplication of two matrices

Tags: matrices, notation, permutations

Matrix multiplication is not commutative, so $P_0 \cdot P_1 \neq P_1 \cdot P_0$. I have a problem where I multiply $P_1^i \cdot P_0^{n-i}$, but not just in this way $P_1 \cdot P_1 \cdot \ldots \cdot P_0 \cdot \ldots \cdot P_0$, but all possible permutations of multiplying $i$ times the matrix $P_1$ with $n-i$ times the matrix $P_0$.

Is there a notation for this? Right now I'm writing 
$$ \Pi(P_1^i \cdot P_0^{n-i}) $$
and explain what I mean below.

Comment: Do you mean $\prod_{i = 0}^n P_0^iP1^{n-1}$

Comment: @MarcBogaerts No, that'd be the $P_0$ matrix right-multiplied with the $P_1$ matrix, neglecting the other possible permutations.